# DataTable Manual Rows Insert: This row already belong to this table

Tags: c#, for-loop, gridview, datatable

I am trying to fill a gridview with manually created datatable. I have two tables one is "hr_vacancy" second is "hr_profile". have matching column " 'designation' and 'scale'. in hr_vacancy there is a column 'working'.

I have to show number of records in gridview which are dependent on 'working' quantity. If in working I have (e.g 3 quantity) then I'll check in profile weather there are 3 profiles inserted with same 'designation' which has 3 quantity in 'hr_vacancy.working' column.

Let's say if two profiles are entered, the gridview will show two records from 'hr_profile' and one empty row having that designation in it only. I have written some code which is attached. but when I bind new 'dr' to datatable it shows error that 'this row already belong to this table'

```
User user = new User();
Util myUtil = new Util();
DbManager dbManager = new DbManager();
string strSQL = "";

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataTable dttempEmployee = new DataTable("TempEmployee");
        strSQL = "Select hfmiscode from profile where hfmiscode='1'";
        dttempEmployee = dbManager.FillDataTable(strSQL);
        DataRow dr = dttempEmployee.NewRow();

        strSQL = "select * from hr_vacancy where hfmiscode='398101' order by CONVERT(int, scale) desc";
        DataTable dtVacancy = dbManager.FillDataTable(strSQL);

        if (dtVacancy.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            int intRowCountVacancy=0;
            string strDesignation = string.Empty;
            string strWorking = string.Empty;

            intRowCountVacancy = dtVacancy.Rows.Count;

            for (int i = 0; i < intRowCountVacancy; i++)
            {
                strDesignation = Convert.ToString(dtVacancy.Rows[i]["Designation"]);
                strWorking = Convert.ToString(dtVacancy.Rows[i]["working"]);

                for (int j = 0; j < Convert.ToInt32(strWorking); j++)
                {
                    strSQL = "select * from profile where hfmiscode='398101' and designation='" + strDesignation +"'";
                    DataTable dtProfileGet = dbManager.FillDataTable(strSQL);

                    if (dtProfileGet.Rows.Count > 0 || dtProfileGet.Rows.Count == Convert.ToInt32(strWorking))
                    {
                        if (j != Convert.ToInt32(strWorking))
                        {
                           // dttempEmployee.NewRow();

                            if (dtProfileGet.Rows[j]["hfmiscode"] == DBNull.Value)
                            {
                                dr["hfmiscode"] = "-";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                dr["hfmiscode"] = Convert.ToString(dtProfileGet.Rows[j]["hfmiscode"]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (j != Convert.ToInt32(strWorking))
                        {
                               // dttempEmployee.NewRow();
                                dr["hfmiscode"] = "-";
                        }
                    }
                    dttempEmployee.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
            }
        }
        GridView1.DataSource = dttempEmployee;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

**Note**: I have used 'hfmiscode' only one column from hr_profile table. Later I'll add more columns.

Comment: Pro tips for asking questions: do not adding urgent/ASAP begging - your questions is not more important than anyone elses. Make an effort with your post, and ensure that sentences start with an upper case letter, and the same for "I" when referring to yourself. Don't ask for one-on-one support via TeamViewer - this takes up far more time than volunteers can usually afford to offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do datatable.NewRow(), it is created in datatable with default values for all the columns in it. It returns the newly created object of datarow and you need to populate column with appropriate values.

The issue here is you have datatable.NewRow() statement outside of for loop and datatable.Row.Add is called in for loop.
So basically you are trying to add the same row multiple times.

You need to move datatable.NewRow() statement inside inner for loop which as following.

```
 for (int j = 0; j < Convert.ToInt32(strWorking); j++)
 {
    var dr = dttempEmployee.NewRow();

    // Other logic

    dttempEmployee.Rows.Add(dr);
 }
```

Comment: thanks. but i stuck in a new problem. after some iterations suddenly this error received "There is no row at position 2.". this error comes in
`if (dtProfileGet.Rows[j]["hfmiscode"] == DBNull.Value)
                                {
                                    dr["hfmiscode"] = "-";
                                }`

Comment: The reason behind this is dtProfileGet have only 2 rows and you are trying to access third row by doing dtProfileGet.Rows[2]. You need to make sure that you do not pass value more than totalrows-1 to dtProfileGet.Rows

Comment: Dear, i am unable to find the exact error point in it. if i give u my teamview id . will u please connect and tell me the issue. it would be very grateful. please

Comment: I am not near my computer right now. Can you debug your code and figure out which line causes the error?

Comment: Line 59:                                 if (dtProfileGet.Rows[j]["hfmiscode"] == DBNull.Value)

Comment: this line is showing error. its very important for me to complete this task by today evening. your support is not less than a great hope for me.

Comment: my hr_vacancy table has 90 records. where in each row 'hr_vacancy. working' column has different integer values. from 1 to 58 iteration my code works fine and add new row to datatable but at 58 iterations of 'i' loop it shows this error in sub loop of 'j'

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, this issue is because of the row not availbale at the specific index.  How can you tell that the issue is occuring at 58th iteration only? You have hardcoded value 398101 in strSQL. That also could be the cause behind this issue.

Comment: Dear issue has been resolved.. thank you for your humble support. stay blessed.